# ECAD Program that knows about breakout boards?

Tags: cad

Are there any ECAD/layout programs that know about popular breakout boards in their component libraries?  For example, pieces like an [ESP32 Dev Board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09GK74F7N) or [TB6612FNG breakout board.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08J3S6G2N)

(note) I am not asking for information on sourcing these kinds of parts, just how to use them in ECAD / board layout software.

Comment: Which programs have you checked. already? Have you looked into KiCad libraries?

Comment: Why not make your own footprints?

Comment: Why would you use dev boards for a non-dev application? Maybe to make them pluggable, but then shouldn't you be footprinting sockets--? And yes, making footprints yourself most likely, unless you find a footprint that happens to fit (DIP sockets?).

Answer (score 2):

Aside from making your own footprints (which is simple for devices like this that are just two row of pins), you can get them for common development boards easily enough online.

For example, SnapEDA has this for the ESP32:  https://www.snapeda.com/parts/ESP32-DEVKITC-32D/Espressif%20Systems/view-part/

Which includes the footprint, symbol and a 3D CAD model.  You can find similar files for many common boards.

In any case, be sure to double check any footprints you download against the datasheet before you order boards.  You will save your self a lot of frustration.

---

As for that breakout board, since you are making your own PCB, you probably don't need it.  You can simply use the footprint (included in KiCAD) for the underlying IC and put it onto your board directly.  This is more simple, more compact and cheaper.